# Firebase Cloud Function - the best alternative to get DB values from a list of cases

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I need to create a firebase cloud function that return some realtime-database values from a list of userIds.

I know that the following code is not correct, but just to example:

```
async function checkStatus(uids, admin) {
    let db = admin.database();
    let retJSON = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < uids.length; i++) {
        let uid = uids[i];
        let ref = db.ref(`users/${uid}/status`);
        ref.once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
            retJSON[uid] = snapshot.val(); 
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(`Error on uid: ${uid}`);
            retJSON[uid] = 'not found';
        });
    }

    return retJSON;
};
```

What is the best approach to do this? I'd like to avoid getting all users and then check/compare with the userId list (uids parameter).

How could I do this?

Tks!

Comment: I don't think you can avoid making multiple queries unless you want to query all of /users at once.

Comment: Note that the overhead of those calls is quite small, since Firebase pipelines the requests over a single connection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786